# using this keyword in function javascript dojo toolkit

Tags: javascript, dojo, this

I have a javascript module in javascript dojo toolkit. But I have a problem about using this keyword.

```
 define(["dojo/_base/declare","database/tool"],
        function (declare, databaseTool) {
            return declare(null, {
                person: null,
                spatialReference: null,

                constructor: function (parameters) {
                    this.person = parameters.person;                    
                },

                activatePerson: function () {

                    var db = new databaseTool();

                    var personOptions = {
                        "isActivated": true
                    };

                    var onActivated = function(result) {
                        var updatedPerson = result.person;
                        var oldPerson = this.person; //retuns <div id="person"/>
                    };

                    db.update(personOptions, onActivated );
                }
            });
        })
```

I want to use `person object` of module  in `onActivated` method via **this** keyword.
But this.person does not return javascript object. it returns `<div id="person...>`

Comment: See this question (pun intended): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword . Dojo has a `hitch` function for dealing with this: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo has a function for that called [`hitch()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch) (from the `dojo/_base/lang` module). Your solution would be:

```js
var onActivated = function(result) {
    var updatedPerson = result.person;
    var oldPerson = this.person; //retuns <div id="person"/>
};

db.update(personOptions, lang.hitch(this, onActivated) );
```

It accepts two parameters, the first one being the object used as **scope** (`this`) and the second one begin the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var context = this;
 var onActivated = function(result) {
      var updatedPerson = result.person;
      var oldPerson = context.person;
 };
```

try that way.